# Instagram audience within Advertising Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, advertising-studio

I see on Salesforce help page that it's possible to create an audience for Instagram, bu I don't see possibility to establish a connection with Instagram in Advertising Studio.

How to create an Instagram audience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Facebook and Instagram share the same Meta Business Suite, where you manage your campaigns, ads and audiences, you should just connect Advertising Studio with Facebook.

You will have the choice in Meta Business Suite, to choose either Facebook, Instagram or both, when creating new campaigns - utilizing the Audience shared from Marketing Cloud.